# tmux - Making new session with the name of the current one plus '-2'

Tags: tmux, session

```
bind S new-session -s "#{session_name}"-2 -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

Literally creates a session called `#{session_name}-2`. How do i properly interpolate the session name?